# ASP.NET Passing Data Between Multiple Pages Session

Tags: asp.net

So there seems not be any pretty answer to the question of how pass data between multiple pages. After having done a little homework here's why (or at least what I've gleaned):

1. ViewState variables don't persist across pages.
2. Session variables are volatile and must be used sparingly.
3. Cookies have potential safety issues and take time and must be kept small.
4. Storing vars in the URL has limits to the amount of data and can be unsafe.
5. Storing vars temporarily in a db is a real pita because you add one table per object that might be potentially passed to another page.

   So far it is looking like I will be using hidden fields to pass a keyid and unique id to the next page and then retrieve the data from the db. What are your thoughts on all of this? What is the best way to go about doing any of it? I am early in the development of this app, so making changes now is preferred.

edit: I am anticipating a lot of users using this application at any one time, does that affect whether or not I should be using SQL Server based Session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session variables should work fine for your needs.

I would go with StateServer or SQLServer Session state mode. Using mode InProc is the fastest, but it has some issues (including all user sessions getting dropped when a new binary is pushed, web.config changes, etc). Sessions are volatile, but you can control the volatility in several ways. Sessions require cookies unless they are configured as cookieless (which I highly recommend  you stay away from), but I think that is a reasonable requirement.

Also, you can create a struct or serializable class from which you create objects that you can store in a session variable. The struct or class will allow you to keep all of your data in one place - you only have one session variable to worry about.

There is going to be advantages and disadvantages for any method, it's all about finding the **best** method. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to persist state, yes store it in the database since you don't have to worry about an expiration.  The `Session` is similar except you have to worry about the `Session` expiring.  In both cases concurrent calls that write similar data to the same area could cause problems and need to be accounted for.

`Session` is good when you don't have to worry about multiple web servers or timeout issues.  The database gives you more scalability but at a cost of doing lots of db read/writes and you have to consider clean up.

Personally I would try to use the following decision tree:

1. Is the data simple, short and not private -> query string
2. Is the data less simple but only needs to exist for a short time -> session
3. Will the data be needed across multiple area and be persistent for long period of time -> database

Of course there is more to it that this but that should give you a basic outline of considerations since you are just starting out.  Keep it simple.  Don't try to over engineer a solution if a simple query string will suffice.  You can always over engineer late as long as you have kept it simple to start.

Comment: +1 - I like your basic decision tree, good way to boil it down. I would only add that query string should really just be used for "gets". That is, don't make a form that uses a anything in a query string to determine a database update action when the target page is loaded. Search engines, bookmarks, code that doesn't deal with conditions right, all will cause you problems.

Answer (score 3):

I think context is important here, e.g. what are you trying to pass between pages and why?

If you are dealing with complex, multi-part forms, then you can implement the form in a single page, simply showing or hiding relevant element. Use usercontrols and custom controls as much as possible to facilitate isolation and reusability. This makes life a lot easier across the board.

Anything that is user-generated is almost certainly going to end up in a database anyway - so #5 does not seem relevant. That is you shouldn't have to store data "temporarily" in a database- what data would need to be persisted between pages that isn't part of your application.

Anything else would seem to be session related and not that much data.

I could add some more thoughts if I knew what specifically you were dealing with.

Oh - "cookies have potential safety issues and take time" - you're going to use cookies, unless you don't want to be able to identify return visitors. Any potential safety issues would only be a result of bad implementation, and certainly passing  data in hidden fields is no better. And you really don't want to get into writing an ASP.NET app that is designed around pages posting to forms other than itself. That's just a headache for many reasons and I can't think of a benefit of doing this as part of basic application design.

Comment: +1.  This type of thing can't really be evaluated outside of context.  Also your other points are right on target.

Answer (score 0):

All methods have their pros and cons. It would all depend on the scenario you are working in.

Session variables work quite well if used within reason. InProc sessions in traffic heavy sites can quickly drain your resources but you can always switch to SQL Server based session that does most of the DB work for you.

Comment: I am anticipating a whole lot of users using the site at any given time. @Kelsey mentioned the problems that come with DB read/writes and that is where I am at now. It seems highly problematic to read/write every time I want to pass data, and then clean up somehow afterwards. Does the Sql Server based Session do this for me? How would I set this up?

Comment: Create a db table that will store whatever data you need for each user. Create a struct or serializable class that models that table. When someone logs in, load their record from the db, populate the struct or object, and store it in a session variable. If their data changes while logged in, update the corresponding database row. I would recommend using a serializable class so that you can define methods for making db calls (e.g. loading a user, updating a user, etc).

Comment: Still not sure what exactly you're struggling with here. What data do you need to pass between pages on any regular basis outside of basic session/auth info? Also, while thinking about architecture is good, don't overthink. Write good code first. Optimize later. It's easy to swap out a mechanism for storing data (assuming you follow the DRY principle) if/when there'a performance problem. Databases are damn fast, and hardware is cheaper than programmer time, too.