# How to show the values of each controls when I return to the page?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I've a multiple page registration from where I want to show the previous page controls data when moving back to the page again. I am coding on asp.net, c# and JavaScript.
Can anyone help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a caching mechanism? Save it in a ['Session'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.140).aspx).

Comment: Have you tried using Sessions ?

Comment: This question could be helpful: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120798/asp-net-passing-data-between-multiple-pages-session-question

Comment: yeah, I am using session for store the data for insert into database but I want to show the data when I go back the to page and make some change then go to the next page..

Comment: Why can't you use the same Session you use for insert to retrieve the data when you go back to the page ?

Comment: If you can post a section of your code this would help users to understand more of what you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb(v=vs.140).aspx)

```
string firstName = "Jeff";
string lastName = "Smith";
string city = "Seattle";
Session["FirstName"] = firstName;
Session["LastName"] = lastName;
Session["City"] = city;
```

When you redirect it is a new HTTP request. HTTP is stateless. so it wont keep the data you entered earlier there. You should read it from a persistant storage mecahnism (like Session) and load that to the textboxes.